# Meteor: Aggregate multiple javascript files into one?

Tags: meteor

Drupal has an option to "aggregate" (that is, to combine) multiple js or css files into one, to reduce the number of files going over the network.

Does Meteor have something similar?
Obviously for development it is nicer to have the files all separate. But on production it would be great to have them bundled (and minified).

Comment: I had the same question. Thanks for asking it for me! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Meteor uses separate files on the development server and combines and minifies js and css files on the production server.

For an example view the source of [http://meteor.com](http://meteor.com/).

As a bonus, Meteor has [Smart Packages](http://docs.meteor.com/#packages) that compile various preprocessors, including:

- [LESS](http://docs.meteor.com/#less)
- [Stylus](http://docs.meteor.com/#stylus)
- [CoffeeScript](http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript)

By using the Smart Packages preprocessors, you are free to write the code or styles in your preferred language and Meteor will convert it to javascript or css, on demand.

Comment: +1. As a rule, local development should always use "full" javascript libraries (no need to explicitly source .min.js files locally as the `deploy` process minifies automatically).

Comment: @Kyle: Cool! Does the same apply to less/css?

Comment: @donquixote the current LESS Smart Package converts the LESS to CSS before serving it to the browser. So, unfortunately, you will not see the LESS un-compiled when developing. With Meteor's AutoReload feature this isn't much of a problem, though, because the page will reload on file changes.

Comment: @TimDog, couldn't agree more. Keeping the files separate really speeds up *bug hunting*.

Comment: @Kyle: Sure. My intended question was whether it can be minified and combined into one file, like the js. Looking at the Meteor.com source, this indeed seems to be the case. And just now I notice that this is already answered in your reply :)

Comment: @TimDoug: Agree. Unfortunately our jQuery (that is shipped with meteor, or at least not included in the app folders), is already minified. Do you happen to know where this is configured?

Comment: @donquixote on the development server at [/packages/jquery/jquery.js](http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery/jquery.js) I'm seeing jQuery 1.8.2 un-minified. Here's the [Meteor jQuery Smart Package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/jquery/jquery.js). Is it possible that you have another version of jQuery that could overriding it?

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how does it know if it's in dev vs. production mode? And in development mode (on localhost), how can I force it to combine all JS/CSS, at least to check the combined file works fine before deploying. Thanks.

Comment: @sebastien.b, I'm not sure. Would you mind creating a separate question? The only way that I know of would be to use `meteor bundle`, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Done Kyle, I created a separate one.